# Strip out css selectors from css file without styles

Tags: css, css-selectors, strip

How can I return only the element selectors from a CSS file, one per line?

E.g.

I have a CSS file like this:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #d2b55b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d2b45a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #d2b55b;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #222222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have `sed` etc. available. After transformation the file will look like this:

```
.navbar-default 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a
```

All styles will be stripped out leaving only the CSS selectors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try something like this:

```
sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g' test.css
```

A similar question was asked on unix.stackexchange. See the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166873/how-can-i-delete-all-text-between-curly-brackets-in-a-multiline-text-file) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the link to similar. This produces a file I can work with.